# Canvas to image. Base64 not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**hi hi.**

I cut the image. After drawing it in the canvas. But when I try to turn a canvas into an image through:

```
crop(image, pixelCrop, fileName) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('can')
  canvas.width = pixelCrop.width
  canvas.height = pixelCrop.height
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  let img = new Image()
  img.src = image.preview
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log(img)
    ctx.drawImage(
      img,
      pixelCrop.x,
      pixelCrop.y,
      pixelCrop.width,
      pixelCrop.height,
      0,
      0,
      pixelCrop.width,
      pixelCrop.height,
    );
  }
  let mage = document.getElementById('img')
  mage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")

}
```

I do not get anything. Image is not displayed.

HTML

```
<canvas id="cnvs"></canvas>
<span>
    <img src="" id="img"/>
</span>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You have no elements with an id set to `'image'`? Anyway, check the console of your developper tools, it will probably tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: That's just the point that there is no) It installs a new link in the image tag object (Base64). But nothing is displayed

Comment: Yes onload is async so when you call toDataURL nothing has been drawn on your canvas yet.

Comment: you're damn right! thanks!!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
crop(image, pixelCrop, fileName) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('can')
  canvas.width = pixelCrop.width
  canvas.height = pixelCrop.height
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  let img = new Image()
  img.src = image.preview
  img.onload = async function() {
    console.log(img)
    await ctx.drawImage(
      img,
      pixelCrop.x,
      pixelCrop.y,
      pixelCrop.width,
      pixelCrop.height,
      0,
      0,
      pixelCrop.width,
      pixelCrop.height,
    );
    let mage = document.getElementById('img')
    mage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
  }
}
```